# How to cache content per user?

Tags: users, cache

Is there a way to cache content with the (% cache %} tag on a per-user base?

If user A is logged in, his content gets cached. User B logs in, but his content should not interfere with that of User A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the upcoming Craft 2.2 release, we've added a `using key` parameter to the `{% cache %}` tag for for situations like this.

So you'd be able to do something like this for per user caching:

```
{% cache using key "myImportantUserCache" ~ currentUser.id %}
```

Comment: Have I told you lately, that I love you?

Comment: Not since last night! <wink>

Comment: Awesome, I've been waiting for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add user dependent content in between your `cache` tags to make the cache invalidate itself every time the page is requested by a new user. This probably doesn't help you much (but depends on the use case):

```
{% cache %}
    <div class="hidden">{{ currentUser.id }}</div>
{% endcache %}
```

.

Another idea is to have user specific URLs. That'd work because each URL gets its own cache entry in the DB (see Brad's [comment](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2059/125)<sup>1</sup>).

For the pages in question, add user specific info to the URL in your links:
`<a href="/{{ currentUser.id }}/blog/{{ entry.slug }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>`

and then use [dynamic routes](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing#dynamic-routes) to make them work:
URI format:`<*>/blog/<*>` → Template: `blog/_entry.html`

.

<sup>1: "The cache, by default will cache it's contents on a per URL and per locale basis."</sup>