# Cache not invalidated on publishing new entry

Tags: cache

I'm using `{% cache %}` to cache pages, but it seems that the caches are not invalidated after posting new content, which is what I thought should happen.

I've investigated the situation and what I think is happening is this:

- Post a new entry
- Caches are then deleted (this process takes a looong time: I noticed that templatecacheelements table was up to something like 450,000 rows)
- The page in question is accessed by a visitor while the cache is being invalidated, and so the template is cached again before it has been purged

Because Craft doesn't know about the access to the template during emptying of the caches, I suppose it never will until the cache is purged manually.

Is there anything I can do to improve this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate?  See answer here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2071/57

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you'd be hoping for but the advice I got was to create a plugin to listen and clear the cache when a new entry was published https://twitter.com/craftcms/status/541968671300911104

Comment: I think that tweet assumed you were talking about data caches (by default in `craft/storage/runtime/cache`), not template caches (stored in the database).